# Kendo Hierarchy Grid not showing child table

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a main grid and would like a child table attached to it. The child table data is there, but has a css property of `display:none` and the arrow never animates down.

Main grid:

```
Controls.RenderedGrid = Controls.MainGrid.kendoGrid({
    dataSource: null,            
    filterable: true,
    height: "740px",
    groupable: true,
    sortable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    pageable: true,
    detailInit: Methods.HistoryInit,
    resizable: true,
    columnResizeHandleWidth: 5,
    columnMenu: true,
    reorderable: true,
    columns: [
        { field: "Id", title: "Id", filterable: false, hidden: false, width: 100 },
        { field: "Date", title: "Date", filterable: false, hidden: false, width: 100 },
        { field: "Text1", title: "Text1", filterable: false, hidden: false, width: 65 },
        { field: "Text2", title: "Text2", filterable: false, hidden: false, width: 65 },
        { field: "Text3", title: "Text3", filterable: false, hidden: false, width: 65 }            
    ]
});
```

The `dataSource` gets filled by a `Search` button which makes an AJAX call to an API.

Detail grid that I'm trying to have as the child table:

```
Methods.DidHistoryInit = function (e) {
var attachments = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        { attachmentId: 1321, Name: "Product Roadmap.pptx", Versions: "3", Title: "" },
        { attachmentId: 1322, Name: "Release Timeline.xls", Versions: "1", Title: "" },
        { attachmentId: 1324, Name: "Requirements Analysis.docx", Versions: "2", Title: "" }
    ],
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            expanded: true
        }
    }
});

var versions = [
    { versionId: 1325, attachmentId: 1321, Status: "1321", VersionNumber: "1", Comment: "", Size: "1.23 MB", CreatedBy: "Landry, Kristi", CreationDate: "" },
    { versionId: 1326, attachmentId: 1321, Status: "1321", VersionNumber: "2", Comment: "", Size: "1.87 MB", CreatedBy: "Landry, Kristi", CreationDate: "" },
    { versionId: 1327, attachmentId: 1321, Status: "1321", VersionNumber: "3", Comment: "", Size: "1.91 MB", CreatedBy: "Smith, Michelle", CreationDate: "" },
    { versionId: 1328, attachmentId: 1324, Status: "1324", VersionNumber: "1", Comment: "", Size: "7.41 KB", CreatedBy: "Peters, Stacy", CreationDate: "" },
    { versionId: 1329, attachmentId: 1324, Status: "1324", VersionNumber: "1", Comment: "", Size: "4.43 MB", CreatedBy: "Franklin, Marshall", CreationDate: "" },
    { versionId: 1330, attachmentId: 1322, Status: "1322", VersionNumber: "2", Comment: "", Size: "4.71 MB", CreatedBy: "Peters, Stacy", CreationDate: "" }
];
$("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: versions,
        filter: { field: "attachmentId", operator: "eq", value: e.data.attachmentId }
    }),
    columns: [
        { field: "versionId", title: "Version Id" },
        { field: "Status" },
        { field: "VersionNumber", title: "Version Number" },
        { field: "Comment" },
        { field: "Size" },
        { field: "CreatedBy", title: "Created By" },
        { field: "CreationDate", title: "Creation Date" }
    ]
});
```

When the page is rendered, the child table is `display:none` and when I click on the side arrow on the row, nothing happens.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Did you check the console of your browser? Are there any error messages when loading the page or clicking the arrow?

Comment: The [detailInit](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/detailinit) handler is set to `Methods.HistoryInit` ... shouldn't that be `Methods.DidHistoryInit`?